JSON Request Body Help Plytix / Celigo
I have multiple different scheduled imports going into Plytix mostly around 2 to 8 am from multiple vendors. I have a delta flow to handle these changes. They're usually 120k records and the page size is set to 100. This takes hours as it should but during this time any changes that my coworkers make on Plytix don't reflect on the websites until hours later. I would like to confirm if there's a possibility to create a delta flow that runs between 9 am to 12 am that only accounts for changes between this time disregards the multiple scheduled imports from 2 to 8 am and only accounts for changes my coworkers make from 9 am and beyond to speed things up dramatically. I would love anyone's opinion as this has been a pain to deal with. My current request body:
{
  "filters": [
    [
    {
        "field": "modified",
        "operator": "gt",
        "value": "{{lastExportDateTime}}"
      },
      {
        "field": "attributes.website",
        "operator": "eq",
        "value": "website2"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "attributes": [
"attributes.shopify_title",
"attributes.handle",
"attributes.title_override_checkbox",
"attributes.title_override",
"attributes.sjstatus",
"attributes.product_description",
"attributes.description_override_checkbox",
"attributes.descriptionoverride",
"attributes.item_image_item_image2",
"attributes.image_src",
"attributes.image_override_checkbox",
"attributes.product_type",
"attributes.brand_name",
"attributes.tags",
"attributes.pro_benchmark_retail",
"attributes.map_pricing",
"attributes.usemappricing",
"attributes.cost_per_item",
"attributes.suggested_retail",
"attributes.upc_code",
"attributes.inventory_management",
"attributes.weight",
"attributes.variant_weight_unit",
"attributes.inventory_id",
"attributes.mro_supreme_variant_id",
"attributes.variant_inventory_policy",
"attributes.published",
"attributes.variant_taxable",
"attributes.attributes",
"attributes.attributes_override",
"attributes.attributes_override_checkbox",
"attributes.about_this_item",
"attributes.about_this_item__more_information_checkbox",
"attributes.about_this_item__more_information_override_1",
"attributes.shelf_pack",
"attributes.shelf_pack_quantity",
"modified"
  
  ],
  "pagination": {
  "page": {{add export.http.paging.page 1}},
   "page_size": 100
  }
}

Haven't been successful in finding a solution or something close.

The question is too broad. Please narrow it down to a specific issue or provide more context on what you've tried.
